# How can I see the old episodes of a podcast on iPad?

Tags: ipad, podcasts, podcasts.app

I have noticed that I cannot see all the episodes of a podcast in the feed section, even though I see it on the podcasts website. Can someone tell me how I can access the older episodes ? 
I'd like to watch some episodes not being shown on the app but available on the website.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of podcast where you going to watch / listen?

Comment: Ones about Science. I'm talking about Frontiers in particular here. It's run by BBC

Comment: I am seeing the same content (30 podcasts) on the [official bbc](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006qy5p/episodes/downloads) website and [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/podcast/frontiers/id577389804?mt=2) ?

Comment: @rwzdoorn But, in this link http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006qy5p/episodes/player there are 120 episodes.

Comment: @rwzdoorn There's also a show called Science Friday which only allows access to it's last 10 episodes through the app. How can I get the older episodes?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the author of the podcast. Some authors limit their podcasts on iTunes but do offer them via their website (it gives them extra traffic).

Comment: Is there no way to listen to it rough the app ? It's not organised otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the podcast feed for this particular show only includes the most recent 30 podcasts. To determine that, I looked at the feed source and counted the number of `<item>` tags within the `<channel>` tag.

Unfortunately, there is no way to play shows older than that with a podcast player unless they'd previously been downloaded and saved to your device.

It's true that podcasters often limit this, but normally the limit would be higher — 100 is common, for example. Your best bet for a solution is to contact the show (or the BBC, if direct show feedback isn't possible) and ask them to set the limit high enough that all podcast episodes are available.

Comment: What can I do for other podcasts like the Nature podcast? Also, can you tell me how you checked tags?

Comment: _"What can I do for other podcasts like the Nature podcast?"_ I couldn't find an RSS/podcast link on the show's page or on iTunes. It appears that this show (last broadcast in 2014?) isn't available as a podcast.

Comment: _"Also, can you tell me how you checked tags?"_ From the [podcast tab of the Frontiers show](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006qy5p/episodes/downloads), clicked the **Subscribe** button and selected **RSS**, then selected View > Developer > View Source in my browser. I cleaned up the source XML using a text editor (Atom) and then counted the number of `<item>` tags.